# How to scrape contact data from many websites?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have list of thousands of URLs. I wonder how to crawl contact page and scrape contact data from the URL of the "contact us" page? e.g. address, phone and email.

Any ideas would be helpful.

I am thinking about using regular expressions; they will work for phone and email but scraping address is not possible.

Comment: Locating the addresses is the Named Entity Recognition task. NER is a field in NLP, Natural Language Processing. You can try using e.g. Stanford Named Entity Recogizer which has an implementation for .Net:  
https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordNER.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer is there is not an omnipotent method to do it.. and it involves some human intelligence based on which page you are trying to scrape.

***(1) Collect the info (HTML)***

Since you have already narrowed down your scope to a list of URLs. The correct way to implement it is using whatever tool you have to collect the HTML page first. So you have all the HTML files sitting locally  so every time you tweak your code 'regular expression etc.'. You don't need to spend another hours hitting their server to collect the data. 
***Note, it depends on your purpose, read the terms of services before storing HTML file***

***(2) Parsing***

Now you have the information stored locally in your laptop/server. Now it is just the problem of how to parse it out of HTML. I don't know much about C# and how your list of pages look like. If your contact pages actually comes from the same site... say social media webpages which will follow the same HTML design(which is the best situation), you can use some HTML parser(I use beautifulsoup in python) to locate the tags easily and get the content inside that tag. Then you just need to apply that function to all the HTMLs that you have stored and the job is done.

If the URLs all come from different sites, then you just need to tweak your function and human identify if your parsing results is good enough or not and keep trying....